# How to add GeoJSON info using HTML inner

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I would like to add information about my GeoJSON file after "click". When I am using example from OpenLayers 3.14 it doesn't work. How should I do it?

When I click on the GeoJSON, below I see "undefined". My script is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ol.css'>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
    <script src="build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4-src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
           }),
           new ol.layer.Vector({
              title: 'added Layer',
              source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                 projection : 'EPSG:3857',
                 url: 'gjson/wgr80.geojson'
                 })
              })
           ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center:[0,0],
          zoom:2
        })
      });
 map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  var infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
  infoElement.innerHTML = feature ? feature.get('type') : '';
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works , but i would like add more feature here :` infoElement.innerHTML = feature ? feature.get('type') : ' '; `  eg. type, name, size ....do you know how to do it?

Comment: You can use string-concatination. Javascript provides a concat-Method with Strings: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp. Or just concatenate with +. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting